# Magento resource: custom selects with OR in where (select orders by status)

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, sql

I'm building a custom module and i'm trying get all orders with specific status:

```
$canceledQuery = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->select()
            ->from('mage_sales_flat_order', 'entity_id')
            ->where('status = ?', 'canceled');
```

This works very well. But now i'm trying use OR in where, without successs.
I have been try this:

```
$whereCanceled = array();
foreach ($_status as $statusCode => $value) {
    $whereCanceled[] = sprintf('%s=:%s', 'status', $statusCode);
}

$ordersQuery = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->select()
            ->from('mage_sales_flat_order', 'entity_id')
            ->where(implode(' OR ', $whereCanceled));
```

So, I don't know how use OR right in this case. I found no use for this with OR. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using magento collection standard?

```
Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
  ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('canceled','pending'));
```